# Cómo limpiar el contenido de un matInput con un boton en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Tengo el siguiente modal con dos botones, **Agregar** y **Restablecer**, quiero que al darle click al boton **Restablecer** se borre el contenido que se haya ingresado en el input de la descripción

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>DESCRIPCION</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <mat-label>Nueva Descripción: </mat-label>
                        <input matInput (keyup)="changeDescripcion($event.target)" >
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button mat-button (click)="agregar()">Agregar</button>
            <button mat-button (click)="restablecer()" >Restablecer</button>
        </div>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Probé con lo siguiente pero no hace nada, no borra el contenido de lo que se haya ingresado al input

```
 descripcion: any;
  modelo: Producto = new Producto();
  constructor(private service: CatProductsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  changeDescripcion(e: any) {
    this.descripcion = e.value;
    console.log("DESCRIPCION    " + this.descripcion);

  }


  agregar() {
    this.modelo.descTipo = this.descripcion;
    this.service.registrarDescripcion(this.modelo).subscribe(response => {
      this.modelo = response;
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Éxito',
        text: 'Registro actualizado correctamente'
      });
    });
  }

  restablecer(){
    this.descripcion = '';
  }
```

Comment: Crea un formulario para manejar validaciones y limpiar los campos de forma más fácil.

Comment: te refieres meterlo dentro de un form? o algo asi?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto:

1. Crear una variable de plantilla para el input

   `<input #description matInput (keyup)="changeDescripcion($event.target)" >`
2. Limpiar el valor del input usando la variable

   `<button mat-button (click)="restablecer(); description.value = ''" >Restablecer</button>`